# finding players in the same the team in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to solve a prolog question. I'm trying to print the players who is playing in Arsenal. I couldn't solve the problem.

```
player(rick,arsenal)
player(tom,dortmund)
player(paul,bayern)
player(tim,liverpool)
player(john,arsenal)
player(andrew,arsenal)
```

the output has to be:

```
?- sameteam(????)

X= [rick,john,andrew]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your facts need to be terminated with a "." to be correct Prolog syntax

```
player(rick,arsenal).
player(tom,dortmund).
player(paul,bayern).
player(tim,liverpool).
player(john,arsenal).
player(andrew,arsenal).
```

In "relational database fashion", let's first collect the *ground atoms* (in the sense of "logic atoms", i.e. "facts") that match the condition "plays at arsenal".

Fire up your preferred Prolog, and then:

```
?- [user].
|: player(rick,arsenal).
|: player(tom,dortmund).
|: player(paul,bayern).
|: player(tim,liverpool).
|: player(john,arsenal).
|: player(andrew,arsenal).
|: ^D% user://2 compiled 0.00 sec, 6 clauses
true.

?- player(Who,arsenal).
Who = rick ;
Who = john ;
Who = andrew.
```

Now we just need to "collect them into a list" and we can do that easily using `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(Who,player(Who,arsenal),Players).
Players = [andrew, john, rick].
```

This is all bog-standard "asking the database" work.

We can pack the above into a predicate for easier usage:

```
?- [user].
|: sameteam(Players) :- setof(Who,player(Who,arsenal),Players).
|: ^D% user://3 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- sameteam(Players).
Players = [andrew, john, rick].
```